# Creating a domain object from an Infrastructure service and apply business logic

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm tasked with developing an application which is going to track what an end user does in a session.

My application doesn't handle user registration or anything related to user. The user management is a different bounded context(a separate micro service in my case.) But my application would need to identify an user from a user card(my application would receive the card information.). I would need to call the User micro service with the card information to get user details back. And with the details received, I would need to apply business rules(these rules are part of my domain) to verify if this user can create a session or not.

This is my handler in the Application layer,

```
public async Task<int> Handle(CreateSessionCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Get Player details from third party service from the Infrastructure layer
        var playerSearch = await _playerService.GetPlayerByCardAsync(request.CardTrack);

        //Create a domain object from the search details.
        Player player = new Player(playerSearch.Id, playerSearch.Name, playerSearch.Age);

        //Apply domain rules 
        if (player.CanCreatePlayerSession())
        {
            //
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This is my Player domain entity,

```
public class Player
{
    public Player(int id, string name, int age)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public bool CanCreatePlayerSession()
    {
        return this.Age > 18;
    }
}
```

Is creating a domain object from a Infrastructure service a good DDD approach? Are there any better ways of doing something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following: is `Player` owned by your domain or by some external system's domain?

If your system owns `Player`, the latter should basically reflect GetPlayerByCardAsync's response (PlayerService constructs full player object for you, probably by calling another api or directing querying a storage).

But also if `Player` is owned by an external system, or by a legacy system within your domain, you should count on that system to construct this object.

So we can see that in all above cases a somewhat external component, encapsulated inside an infrastructure service, is responsible for the construction of `Player`. And deserialization is performed directly inside that infrastructure service.

But when dealing with external/legacy systems, it is sometimes necessary to perform adaptations (the anti-corruption layer pattern). From your code sample I can assume that you have that need, since you present the method `CanCreatePlayerSession`. That actually means that you have two separate domain objects for a player: the one that returns from PlayerService, and the one constructed by you. I would recommend to use more accurate semantics, e.g. `CardPlayer` and `SessionPlayer`.

The instruction to construct `SessionPlayer` object, however, should, in line with your code sample, come from the application layer, as it is part of application flow.

Comment: Anti-corruption layer works perfectly for me. I can add the translation logic in there and get my domain object and then apply the business rules.